# GridView -NullPointerException Error -Trying to access the "child imageview"

Tags: java, android

Here I have created Gridview of 64 Imageviews (in xml)and based on the input string trying to load different images at different locations.

```
package com.example.android.chess;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView  = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);  //gridView null


    String FEN="/rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR/";
    LoadPosition(gridView, FEN);
}
  public void LoadPosition(GridView gridView, String FEN)
{ 
    int i=0;
    ImageView child;
    for(int l=0; l<gridView.getCount(); l++) {
         child= (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(l);
         char c = FEN.charAt(i);
        if (c=='/')
            i=i+1;

        else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                i=i+1;                
                l = l + c-1;
        }

        else
            {
            child = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(l);
            c = FEN.charAt(i);
            LoadPieceImage(child,c);
             i=i+1
            }

    }
}
```

}

LoadPieceImage(child,c); is a method which loads different images based on the char c.

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException , gridView is showing as null and
hence gridView.getChildAt(i).

xml...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#8C8C8C"
    >
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#8C8C8C"
        android:gravity="center" />       
           ....................................
      </GridView>
     </ScrollView>
```

please help me to fix it

Comment: now  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); creates error

 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView.............................
 at com.example.android.chess.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)

Comment: Hello please somebody tell me Why I am getting this error, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the contentview to find the gridview with findViewByID you should try this: (Or simply change the GetView function of the gridview and use it to take the superb view from there)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout); // attach the layout
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid); // id should be found now
```

*ps. Also I couldnt see where you set the adapter to the gridview maybe that might cause an issue as well.*

Comment: I am using GridView  setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout); is creating error, setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is only possible,but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble figuring out where your gridview has been specified. Could you post your layout xmls as well?

Is the gridview in your activity_main XML? If so, you have to use the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Otherwise the activity has no reference to find the gridview. The method `findViewById()` implies that a view has been set.

Right now your activity doesn't know there's a view it needs to inflate. Without that, you can't get references to any other view within it. So it's no wonder why the gridview reference is null

Also, looking at the rest of your code, I think you are trying to do the job of an adapter using that for loop. Gridview adapters are made to do what you are trying to do with that for loop

**After posting XML:**
Is what you posted activity_main.xml? If so, gridview should be found but gridview MUST have items inserted into it through an adapter.  Please consider looking at the links I have attached below.

Resources:

[Gridview intro](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

[Gridview + ImageView example](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)

Comment: Modified  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView  = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);  //gridView null

Comment: Thanks for your links I will go through them.
Why is it not possible to search by id then work with them individually?
Adapter is a idea to change and update the Gridview with new set of information,Sometimes it can be useful.But if I want change and update very few of them, then my try search by id can be very useful
May be I am wrong, Please kindly share your views on these....Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right. But because it isn't the supported/recommended way, it can be prone to bugs and issues that others may not be able to help you with. Also, it seems that you making a chess game of sorts. I recommend you use a game engine if you'd like to make it into an actual game.